# Angular 5 refresh component from service

Tags: angular

I am somehow struggling to get a grasp of the architecture.

I have a search component, a table component, a table service.

1. When I do a search I call a rest webservice and getback a JSON. I store this json using a tableservice.setData();
2. I go to the table component page it is working and my data is in the table
3. I search again but this time on the table component page (after it has been initialized) and it is not getting updated as it is already instanciated and it is not going through the component constructor again.

What am I missing is a way to force a refresh of the table component within the table service when my data changes.

Is there any way to achieve this?

**tablecomponent.ts**

```
constructor(private service: SmartTableService) {
    console.log("entering constructorSTable")
    const data = this.service.getData();
    this.source.load(data);
}
```

**searchcomponent.ts**

```
constructor(private searchService: NbSearchService,
            private http: HttpClient, 
            private myTableService : SmartTableService ) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchService.onSearchSubmit()
            .subscribe((data: { term: string, tag: string }) => {
                 var req = this.http.post('http://...', {
                 ...
    }).subscribe(
        res => {
          var ApiRet = res;
          this.myTableService.setData(ApiRet);
        },
        err => {
          console.log("Error occured");
        }
      );
  });
```

the tableservice just contains a setter and getter for the data.

Comment: Can you please add the snippet of your code for better  understanding

Comment: Can you provide more details on how these components and the service are wired up? Are the components part of a larger component?

Comment: edited for  details

Comment: Your service needs to have an RxJS [Behavior]Subject, which emits the latest data. Your table component needs to subscribe on this subject to get the data. This is illustrated in the doc: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: are you using any 3rd party table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has a asimilar issue and try using this code

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

    constructor(private service: SmartTableService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){

        this.subscription = this.service.getData().subscribe(data => { 
           this.source.load(data);
        });

    setInterval(() => {
       this.ref.detectChanges()             
    }, 1000);


   }
```

it is going to force to load the dom every one second.

Answer (score 0):

**tablecomponent.ts**

```
subscription: Subscription;
constructor(private service: SmartTableService) {
    this.subscription = this.service.getData().subscribe(data => { 
        this.source.load(data);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

**table.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SmartTableService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    updateData(data: any) {
        this.subject.next({ data: data });
    }

    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

**searchcomponent.ts**

```
...
.subscribe(
    res => {
      var ApiRet = res;
      this.myTableService.updateData(ApiRet);
    },
    err => {
      console.log("Error occured");
    }
);
...
```